# Tailwind styles in nextjs not working until I apply in parent component, then apply in child again

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

my nextjs code is exhibiting a very strange behaviour.

I have an app/(dashboard)/journals/new/pages.js page that uses a layout with a sidebar and a main section>
In this my pages file, I am trying to create the content section, which is the child passed to the layout component by nextjs.

The problem is that when I apply styles to this page, the styles don't work. However, if I copy the component with the styles to the layout.tsx page, and save, then remove it, the ones in the pages.jsx file sticks. So basically, nextjs only recognises styles that I have copied to the layout.tsx file. But this is not the same for other components and pages. Does anyone have an idea?

```
// app/(dashboard)/journals/new/pages.tsx

import {
  ResizableHandle,
  ResizablePanel,
  ResizablePanelGroup,
} from "@/components/ui/resizable";

const NewJournal = () => {
  return (
      <div className="w-full min-h-screen flex flex-col">
        <div className='text-3xl text-blue-900 h-36 bg-red-400'>testing</div>
        <div className="w-full">
          <ResizablePanelGroup
            direction="horizontal"
            className="w-full rounded-lg border"
            autoSaveId='maistoria-panel'
          >
            <ResizablePanel defaultSize={80}>
              <div className="flex h-[200px] items-center justify-center p-6">
                <span className="font-semibold">One</span>
              </div>
            </ResizablePanel>
            <ResizableHandle />
            <ResizablePanel defaultSize={20}>
              <div className="flex h-[200px] items-center justify-center p-6">
                <span className="font-semibold bg-red-950 m-4">One</span>
              </div>
            </ResizablePanel>
          </ResizablePanelGroup>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};

export default NewJournal;


// app/(dashboard)/layout.tsx


"use client"

import MobileSidebar from '@/components/dashboard/MobileSidebar';
import Sidebar from '@/components/dashboard/Sidebar';
import Logo from '@/components/logo';

const DashboardLayout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <main className='flex'>
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="md:hidden">
        <MobileSidebar />
      </div>
      <section className='w-full min-h-screen'>
        {children}
      </section>
    </main>
  )
}

export default DashboardLayout;
```

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss"

const config = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
  prefix: "",
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: "0" },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: "0" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
} satisfies Config

export default config
```

Note that the styles work in other pages and components correctly.

Comment: Sounds like a misconfigured tailwind.config

Comment: The styles work in other pages and components.

Comment: we have to pass the `content` key in the config of tailwind in which we pass the page to track for tailwind styles. Can you check if that contains the file that you need to modify?

Comment: @NikhilTayal yes. I have also updated the question with the tailwind config. I used the defaults.